# Как многократно использовать функцию REPLACE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Использую функцию `REPLACE` для замены значений в строке, например:

```
SELECT REPLACE('THE NEW VALUE IS #VAL1#','#VAL1#','55') from dual;
```

Это нормально для замены одного значения.

А что, если 20+ значений, надо ли использовать 20+ функций `REPLACE`?
Или есть более практичное решение?

---

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Multiple REPLACE function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947623) от участника [@Аdnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222159/adnan)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947623

Answer (score 2):

Возможно заменить вложенные вызовы `REPLACE()` регулярным выражением. Это намного быстрее, чем вложенные `REPLACE()`, и намного проще и понятней.

Чтобы заменить строки `'a','b','c'` на `'d'` в символьном столбце из заданной таблицы, выполните следующие действия:

```
select regexp_replace(string_col, 'a|b|c', 'd') from given_table
```

Это не что иное, как регулярное выражение для нескольких статических шаблонов с оператором `or`.

Будьте осторожны со специальными символами в регулярном выражении!

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547494) от участника [@user3270011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270011/user3270011)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Не всегда так просто получится заменить вложенные вызовы `REPLACE()` регулярным выражением. Например, если требуется каждый токен заменить не одним единственным, а только ему соответствующим значением.

Конечно, вложенные вызовы будут работать:

```
select replace (replace (replace ('abc', 
    'a', 'd'), 
    'b', 'e'),
    'c', 'f') result
from dual;

RESULT
--------
def
```

Но с увеличением числа и длины значений, код с вложенными вызовами будет выглядеть уже не так красиво и понятно.

Можно поместить значения поиска и замены в отдельную таблицу и воспользоваться небольшой вспомогательной функцией, которую можно объявить прямо в запросе:

```
create table params (id, key, val) as 
    select 1, 'a', 'd' from dual union all
    select 2, 'b', 'e' from dual union all
    select 3, 'c', 'f' from dual;

create or replace type kvarg is object (key varchar2 (32), val varchar2 (32))
/
create or replace type kvargs is table of kvarg
/
with 
function replaceall (str varchar2, kv kvargs) return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (32767) := str;
begin
    for i in 1..kv.count loop
        ret := replace (ret, kv(i).key, kv(i).val); 
    end loop;
    return ret;
end;
param (args) as (
    select cast (multiset (
        select key, val 
        from params order by id) as kvargs) 
    from dual
)
select replaceall ('abc', args) result
from dual, param;

RESULT
--------
def
```

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ea96bc0d7ae9cd910560597747a6fb17).

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать свою функцию, которая будет искать и заменять.

Запрос будет вида:

```sql
SELECT MY_PKG.MY_REPLACE(...) from dual;
```

А внутри функции спрятать все эти 20 реплейсов.

Правда, если нужно в будет в функцию передавать 20 параметров, то тоже не очень красиво. Но хотя бы в самом запросе будет:

```
MY_PKG.MY_REPLACE(..20 параметров..)
```

, а не:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(..20 раз..)))
```

, что по-моему немного лучше.

А если замены жёстко заданы и их передавать в функцию не нужно, то будет совсем хорошо.

Comment: В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1341631/217579) вроде так и сделано, как вы предлагаете. Или в чём состоит отличие?

Comment: В ответе говорится про ```with function```, я же говорю про отдельный пакет или функцию. Я просто к тому что можно хранить логику не в селекте, а где-то совсем отдельно. Хотя смысл по факту тот же.